# Property 'accessToken' does not exist on type 'AuthCredential'

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

By running ionic serve I get the following error:

```
Property 'accessToken' does not exist on type 'AuthCredential'.
// You can use it to access the Google API.
let token = result.credential.accessToken;
```

I have updated my firebase from `firebase: ^4.12.1` to `firebase: ^5.5.9`

This is my ionic info output

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.1.2
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.0.0
   Cordova Plugins       : no whitelisted plugins (19 plugins total)

System:

   NodeJS : v10.13.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 5.8.0
   OS     : Windows 10
```

and this is the method in the `auth.service.ts`

```
signInWithGoogle() {
   console.log('Sign in with google');
   return this.oauthSignIn(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
}

private oauthSignIn(provider: AuthProvider) {
   if (!(<any>window).cordova) {
        return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider).then(() => {
            this.saveUserDetails('gmail');
        });
   } else {
       return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithRedirect(provider)
           .then(() => {
              return this.afAuth.auth.getRedirectResult().then(result => {
                 // This gives you a Google Access Token.
                // You can use it to access the Google API.
                let token = result.credential.accessToken;
               // The signed-in user info.
                let result_user = result.user;

                this.saveUserDetails('gmail');

                console.log(token, result_user);
      }).catch(function (error) {
         // Handle Errors here.
         alert(error.message);
      });
   });
  }
}
```

Why does the accessToken property not exist on the AuthCredential object?

Comment: Did you managed to fix this?

Comment: @CamiloCasadiego replace `let token = result.credential.accessToken;` with `let token = (<any>result).credential.accessToken;`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to cast the `AuthCredential` to `OAuthCredential` which has the `accessToken` property: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/auth-types/index.d.ts#L244

Comment: Do you have the import location, I can't find where to import `OAuthCredential` from `@angular/fire` and auto-import won't find it.

Comment: This works, but how can we know this is a good practice? If Firebase wanted us to be able to get the accessToken (or the idToken in my case) from the auth result, they would have exposed it on the callback, don't you think?

Answer (score 9):

As suggested by @bojeil casting worked for me

```
firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithPopup(this.provider)
      .then(result => {
        // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
        const credential = result.credential as firebase.auth.OAuthCredential;
        const token = credential.accessToken;
        // The signed-in user info.
        const user = result.user;
```

Answer (score 3):

The error occurs due to typescript definitions

Replace

`let token = result.credential.accessToken;`

with

`let token = (<any>result).credential.accessToken;`

Comment: Hello, how can I do this in Objective-C?

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the definition of AuthCredential. If it's [this one](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AuthCredential), it does not have an accessToken property.

Comment: That is android documentation, no the javascript one.